# Identifying this turbine piece with a stud and a Technic axel

Tags: part-identification, vintage

I promise that I don't simply dump photos on here without researching them.  I've been using Bricklink's system for 15 years, and it still perplexes me occasionally...such as this bizarro part.

I swear I went though nearly every possible category this weekend (and all of the Technic groups), and I can't find it.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's part [4869 - Engine, Smooth Large, Center](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4869&name=Engine,%20Smooth%20Large,%20Center&category=%5BAircraft%5D).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd have never guessed it was the center to a jet engine, to represent the turbines...!